# (Solved) Difficulty installing BCM43142 offline for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I am a complete noob, i just installed ubuntu and came across "no wifi adapters found".
Ive been following other answers on this topic but i keep getting stuck. Not sure how to attach those answers as a reference.

I typed in the terminal

lspci -nn -d 14e4:

And got

Broadcom limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

And ive been trying to get  bcmwl-kernel-source.

I am on ubuntu 18.04 and i manually searched on my usb boot disc and copied and pasted the two files to my home directory?(main page i guess)
They are called:

bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

And

dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb

When i open the first file it doesnt list BCM43142 as included in the package and clicking install doesnt seem to do anything. Can somebody prease herp meee

Comment: Are the files in your home directory or on the desktop? From the terminal: `sudo updatedb && locate bcmwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It says: /home/myusername/desktop/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Please post any errors.

**EDIT**: Please download build-essential and all its dependencies, marked with red dots, and transfer them to your desktop. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential Install them as above:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i some_package*.deb
```

Of course, if you can even temporarily get an internet connection by ethernet or tethering, it is as simple as:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

All the dependencies will be resolved automatically.

**EDIT 2**: I believe that most, perhaps all, of the packages are on the install DVD. Insert the DVD and run:

```
sudo apt-cdrom -m -d /media/cdrom add
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Post any errors or warnings.

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dkms: dkms depends on gcc; however: package gcc is not installed. dkms depends on dpkg-dev; however: package dpkg-dev is not installed. dkms depends on make |build essential; however: package make is not installed. Package build-essential is not installed.        dpkg: error processing package dkms (--install): dependency problems- leaving unconfigured processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2)...Errors were encountered while processing: dkms.        This is from the first command

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: The second command gives a similar answer. Im typing all this through my phone, sorry if this writing structure is hard to read

Comment: No problems. We needn't see the exact result.

Comment: I clicked the link above and im unsure what to click on, could you please tell me how to download it?

Comment: I assume yours is a 64-bit installation; confirm: `arch` If it returns x86_64, then click on amd64, select a mirror location, click it and the download will start. Repeat for all the dependencies.

Comment: Yes it is x86_64. I downloaded build essential and the other five dependencies and transferred them to my desktop. I put to the terminal:  "cd ~/Desktop"  then "sudo dpkg -i build-essential_12.4ubuntu1amd64*.deb"  and error came up saying "dpkg: error processing package build-essential (--install): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured" so then i tried "sudo dpkg -i  g++_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64*.deb" and resulted in "dpkg: error processing package g++...processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2)" did i enter it a wrong way?

Comment: Try to install them all at once! sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: I think build-essential failed because it depends on the other packages that you hadn’t yet installed.

Comment: You were right sir im slowly making progress but more problems lol "g++" depends on "g++-7" and "gcc-7" and "libc6-dev" depends on "libc-dev-bin" and "linux-libc-dev" so i installed 4 more dependencies. But again "g++-7" depends on "libstdc++-7-dev" and "gcc-7" depends on "libgcc-7-dev". It didnt end, installing those 2 more dependencies got this to a point where i needed 10 more dependencies. Is there a way to end this? I need me an independent woman pls

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I had a usb boot disc not a dvd so it didn't seem to work, but i am now typing this on my DESKTOP I HAVE WIFI YAY the main problem was me not knowing how to download packages and using correct commands i follwed that big answer page for broadcom again and it worked :) using your concepts of course. Thank you so much for your help